# Docker: unable to push to insecure private registry

Tags: docker, redhat, redhat-containers

I have tried every fix that I have found on the internet and cant seem to get a solution..

I am able to login to the insecure registry because I have the following in the /etc/sysconfig/docker file:
`other_args="--insecure-registry http://10.3.31.105 --insecure-registry http://harbor.ie.local"`

Here is my login example:

```
docker login --username USERNAME --password 'PASSWORD' http://10.3.31.105
WARNING: login credentials saved in /home/svc.jenkins/.docker/config.json
Login Succeeded
```

My OS version is as follows: `Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago)`

My docker version is as follows:

```
docker version
Client version: 1.7.0
Client API version: 1.19
Go version (client): go1.4.2
Git commit (client): 0baf609
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.7.0
Server API version: 1.19
Go version (server): go1.4.2
Git commit (server): 0baf609
OS/Arch (server): linux/amd64
```

The image that I am trying to push is as follows:

`10.3.31.105/okreach/springboot                         latest              cb4b8dccc4fd        5 hours ago         292.1 MB`

My docker push attempt is as follows:

```
docker push 10.3.31.105/okreach/springboot:latest
Error response from daemon: invalid registry endpoint https://10.3.31.105/v0/: unable to ping registry endpoint https://10.3.31.105/v0/
v2 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://10.3.31.105/v2/: dial tcp 10.3.31.105:443: connection refused
 v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://10.3.31.105/v1/_ping: dial tcp 10.3.31.105:443: connection refused. If this private registry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, please add `--insecure-registry 10.3.31.105` to the daemon's arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need for the flag; simply place the CA certificate at /etc/docker/certs.d/10.3.31.105/ca.crt
```

As you can see, it does not even attempt connecting via http... only https... and adding `--insecure-registry` as an argument does not work out too well for me:

```
docker push --insecure-registry=10.3.31.105 10.3.31.105/okreach/springboot:latest
flag provided but not defined: --insecure-registry
See 'docker push --help'.
```

So if anyone knows the trick to get a successful push to an insecure registry on a RedHat (6.8) system, I would appreciate it :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So problem fixed by changing my `other_args="--insecure-registry http://10.3.31.105 --insecure-registry http://harbor.ie.local` to this `other_args="--insecure-registry http://10.3.31.105 --insecure-registry 10.3.31.105`

For anyone having the same issue... there is not much detailed online about this when using RHEL (6.8)